# Count is different from number of rows returned. How?

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
# SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contestants" WHERE "contestants"."email" = 'example@yahoo.com';   
count 
-------
1 (1 row)
    
# SELECT * FROM "contestants" WHERE "contestants"."email" = 'example@yahoo.com';   
id | email | name | created_at | updated_at | send_confirmation | last_ip | share_key | authentication_configuration_id | display_email | stored_dob 
----+-------+------+------------+------------+-------------------+---------+-----------+---------------------------------+---------------+------------ 
(0 rows)
```

I've got two indexes on that email field.  One for email and one for email and another field (yes, I know this is redundant now).  Perhaps one of the indexes is out of date?  How could that happen and how would I fix it?

Comment: Is there something to prevent the database from having changed between those two queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the statistics. That will update the indexes and make the indexes in sync.
In case of postgres use this statement: `REINDEX INDEX myindex`

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was because we replicated to a newer version of Ubuntu (16.04 -> 20.04) which had some issues with glibc/postgres.  Their wiki page with details is here: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Locale_data_changes

In our case, we're still on Postgres 11 and our indexes are large (100s of gigs). We had to create indexes *concurrently* and then remove the old ones.  If we didn't use concurrently, the table would lock and our app would go down (for hours in our case).

Postgres 11 or lower:

```
ALTER INDEX my_index RENAME TO my_index_old;
CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY my_index ON public.my_table USING btree (key);
DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY index_references_on_key_old;
```

If you're on Postgres 12+ you can use REINDEX:

```
REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY my_index;
```